# Error 404 when attempting to publish page via github

Tags: html, github, publish

I am not having success when trying to publish my basic html page.

Here is my repository:
https://github.com/mathiasgc/mathiasgc.github.io

I have an index.html file in my master repository, as well as the CNAME with the domain name.

Thanks,
Mathias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you forgot to give your index file an extension. You have an index file successfully *in* your repository, but it is simply called `index`. You need to give it a valid index extension - in your case I believe you're looking for `index.html`.

When uploading your index file, make sure to actually call it `index.html` specifically, and not just `index`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense(i was scrolling the scroll down bar and selecting .html). However, I'm trying to add the new .html file and not having any success. I'm typing : "git add ." and  getting no response. I already have an existing repository, and had no problems earlier Any idea's?

Comment: There are two reasons; you have either already added that file, or you haven't made any changes. Have you checked with `git status`? Did you rename the old file, or did you remove it? Don't forget that you'll also need to commit and push before you see any changes.

Comment: Your right! Thanks for being so nice! :D So for future edits, I do "git commit" and "git push"? Is there anything faster? preferably one line?

Comment: All good :) Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)

Comment: Will do! Much appreciated!